# Checking all checkboxes if one checkbox gets checked is not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

My issue is that when I click a "select all" checkbox, the other checkboxes not checked: they remain as is.  also showing boolean is not a function : Js error in write : item.IsSelected(value)

EF - locations binding

```
model.Locations = this.Locations.Where(x => selectedLocationIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToViewModel();
```

===================

### HTML

```
 <p>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: allSelect"/> All
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Locations">
            <td>

                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSelected">
            </td>

            <td>
                <p data-bind="text: Name"></p>
            </td>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<script src="~/Scripts/Entities/Component.js"></script>
    <script>
        //template pattern
        var model = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Model);

            var listViewModel = new ListViewModel(model);

            listViewModel.selectedPeople = ko.observableArray()


            ko.applyBindings(listViewModel);



    </script>
```

Also let me know how get the Id - value to pass Id as Data in Json.

```
function ListViewModel(model) {

var self = this;

self.Locations = ko.observableArray(model.Locations);

var Location = function (label) {
    var self = this;

    self.Label = label;
    self.IsSelected = ko.observable();
};

//self.Locations = ko.observableArray();
self.allSelect = ko.computed({

    read: function () {
        var allSelected = true;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Locations() , function (item) {

            if (!item.IsSelected()) {
                allSelected = false;

            }

        });
        return allSelected; //to trigger the browser default bahaviour
    },
    write: function (value) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Locations(), function (item) {
            item.IsSelected(value);
        });
    }

});
```

}

Comment: You need to provide a fuller example. What is `self.Locations` and what is `IsSelected`? Is it an observable? Because if it is, you are overwriting it with `item.IsSelected = value`. Should that be `item.IsSelected(value)`?

Comment: Just a guess would be to not use a computed for checking all, instead using a function on your viewmodel which changes the observable array which is holding your check'ds and fill it in with all of the possible values

Comment: @Matt Burland : item.IsSelected(value) throwing boolean is not a function thats why added = true... you are saying correct that need to add like item.IsSelected(value).. but throwing booolean is not a function

Comment: @Michael Crook  : i have used before it.. in array get the location and make it checked.. i also need to get the Id with binding value.. how get that Id(primary key): I means i need checkbox check all + get the Id value.. i have tried some examples but still not working

Comment: @dotnetexpert: Then that's your problem. It's not an observable. Or you are clearing it somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Looking at your edit, you are setting `self.Locations = ko.observableArray(model.Locations);`, but what's `model.Locations`? I'm going to bet it's a regular javascript object and not a collection of your `Location` objects with observables. Especially since your `Location` seems to be nested inside your `ListViewModel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IsSelected need to be an observable in order for the screen to update. I've also added self.selectedIds to track the ids that are selected.

```
var Location = function(location) {
    var self = this;

    self.Id = location.Id;
    self.Label = location.Name;
    self.IsSelected = ko.observable(location.IsSelected);
}

self.selectedIds = [];

self.allItemsSelected = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        var allSelected = true;
        self.selectedIds = [];

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Locations(), function (item) {

            if (!item.IsSelected()) {
                allSelected = false;    
            }
            else {
                self.selectedIds.push(item.Id);
            }

        });
        console.debug('selectedIds: ' + self.selectedIds);
        return allSelected; //to trigger the browser default bahaviour
    },
    write: function (value) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Locations(), function (item)
        {
            item.IsSelected(value);
        });
    }
});
```

You are getting the error "boolean is not a function" because you aren't using new Location(location) for each location in your javascript locations.

```
var mappedLocations = $.map(locations, function(location) 
                            { return new Location(location) });

self.Locations = ko.observableArray(locations);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wk7dr/9/

Comment: Hello, I have updated my code : self.IsSelected called in function as you have mentioned. but still not working, can you please check that

Comment: Showing boolean is not a function :   item.IsSelected(value)

Comment: I also want to get primary Key : to pass the other json call which checkbox is checked.

Comment: You are most likely missing self.IsSelected = ko.observable();

Comment: To get the primary key you can easily just store it in the Location object itself.

Comment: Also please do not just edit your question with code from my answer

Comment: Above in you question you need to have if (!item.IsSelected()). You are missing (). Also can you please provide your code for initialising the locations array.

Comment: I have used your demo code, in simple application it is working fine, but when i am using with my code it is not working :

Comment: (!item.IsSelected()) is showing undefined is not a function in console.. your code is fine.

Comment: Can you provide the code that's populating self.Locations()

Comment: also i need not Id of whole checkbox list values, i want id of the child of the checkbox, if i am check only one checkbox from 10 checkboxes, i want to get Id - preimay key of only one checkboxes

Comment: That code that you posted isn't javascript. I need to see the javascript that populates Locations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62822/discussion-between-dotnetexpert-and-wayne-ellery).

Comment: the checkbox check all working fine, if i am add dropdwon to change  the checkboxes value , the child checkboxes automatically checked..